# Android One JSON send Mutilple time send to server

Tags: java, android, json, service, broadcastreceiver

I develop an app which send data to server every 1 minute. It check Internet Connection every minutes and when internet is available app send data to server and after receive success tag it delete table rows of the send data.
But the problem is that it send one JSON Mutliple time before reach success tag to delete table rows.
**Example :** if i send json like **{'amt':100}** then it receive by server like **{'amt':100} {'amt':100} {'amt':100} {'amt':100}...** multiple times  and if sever perform the addition operation of particular tag like amt then it add all tag value save 5 times more the real value of tag.so if amt is 100 then server receive 500

AlarmReceiver.java

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        context.startService(background);
    }
}
```

BackgroundService.java

```
    public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    int debug = 0;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private Context context;
    private Thread backgroundThread;
    Helper hp = new Helper(BackgroundService.this);
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
    Connect cn = new Connect();
    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(BackgroundService.this);
    JSONObject finalObj;
    JSONArray resultSet;
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        this.context = this;
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Do something here
            internet();
            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!this.isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.backgroundThread.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void internet() {
        finalObj = null;
        resultSet = null;
        if (hp.isonline() == true) {
            Log.e("dcn", "net connect");

            if (!dbConnector.isPayTableEmplty()) {
                //  Log.e("syncData", getPaymentJSON());
                hp.generateTxtOnSD(getPaymentJSON());
                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("bulk_pay_json", getPaymentJSON());
                String url = Urls.sync_url;
                aq.ajax(url, params, JSONObject.class, this, "jsonCallBack");
                Log.e("start", "start");

            } else {
                Log.e("syncData", "table is empty");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("dcn", "net not connect");
        }
    }

    public void jsonCallBack(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {
        if (json != null) {
            if (debug == 1 || Urls.debug == true) {
                Log.e("result", json.toString());
                Log.e("url", url);
                Log.e("status", String.valueOf(status.toString()));
            }
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                if ("true".equals(jsonObject.getString("json_integrity"))) {
                    try {

                        String del_pay = dbConnector.deletePayMentTable();
                        hp.generateTxtOnSD(del_pay);
                        Log.d("result", "upload successfully");
                        showNotification();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("result", "error occured");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Ex", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        } else {
            new Helper(this).showToast(Urls.errors[1]);
        }


    }

    private String getPaymentJSON() {
        //get opid from SharedPrefrences
        ArrayList<String> opLn = hp.getOpId(BackgroundService.this);
        ArrayList<String> op = hp.getSaveOpInfo(BackgroundService.this);
        String opid;
        if (Integer.valueOf(opLn.get(0)) != 0) {
            opid = opLn.get(0);
        } else {
            opid = op.get(0);
        }

        // open DB for operation
        dbConnector.open();
        // get customer Table columns
        Cursor cursor = dbConnector.ListAllPayData();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
                if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                    try {
                        rowObject.put("conNo", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.CONNO)));
                        rowObject.put("amount", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.PAIDAMT)));
                        rowObject.put("contact", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.CONTACT)));
                        rowObject.put("lineman", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.LNID)));
                        rowObject.put("time", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.TIME)));
                        rowObject.put("discount", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.DISCOUNT)));
                        rowObject.put("rcpt", "");
                        rowObject.put("remark", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.REMARK)));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            resultSet = new JSONArray();
            resultSet.put(rowObject);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        try {
            finalObj = new JSONObject();
            finalObj.put("error", "false");
            finalObj.put("opid", opid);
            finalObj.put("data", resultSet);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dbConnector.close();
        return finalObj.toString();

    }

}
```

Call Broadcast Receiver

```
private void BrodcastReceiverOn() {
    this.context = this;
    Intent alarm = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if (alarmRunning == false) {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 3000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

I use AQuery for for post and receive because http client is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your IntervalMillis for:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 3000, pendingIntent);
```

It repeats every 3 seconds as the unit is in milliseconds.

Use this

```
final long INTERVAL = 1 * 60 * 1000; // 1 minute
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not a problem its repeats every 1 minutes 10 seconds.I count it